# How do i print out an embedded message in this Discord.py command?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qbzn.png)

I am making my first discord bot and I am stuck on this command. Basically I have a list of a couple headlines and the links to the particular articles and I want to print them out in an embedded message, but I keep getting an unsupported annotation error.

I keep changing the self.send to different things like ctx.send, interaction.send_message but nothing seems to be working

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is not formatted well and also lacks some vital information we can use to help answer to your problem. Please format your code in the question itself (no images) and also provide your full error traceback, what works, what doesn't. Do see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use  of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic Discord bot with a hello command hopefully this helps!

```
#These are basic imports needed to run the Discord bot
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

#This sets the bot to "client" aswell as the command prefix to "!
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

#This is a client event it will print in your terminal once the bot is running
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is ready")

#Here is the hello command
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):

em = discord.Embed(color=0x7a0000, description="Hi im a Discord bot!")
       await ctx.send(embed=em)

client.run('token')
```

Please note you may have to fix the syntax on your own although this should work!